# TweetStream getting timeout Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tweetstream

I am using Ruby2 and Rails4 and added a gem 'tweetstream' and when I am running my code for more than one user then getting "timeout"

```
tweet_client = TweetStream::Client.new
tweet_client.on_reconnect do |timeout, retries|
  end.track("params['user_twitter_handle']}") do |status|
    if status[:retweeted_status].blank?
      puts status.text
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: show us the error you're seeing

Comment: @Anthony track code is not executing each time pointer going into .on_reconnect error